# Provide WLAN Access Point without loosing Mobile Internet on Smartphone

Tags: wireless, internet, wifi

I want my Pi to provide a webpage for Smartphones connected via WLAN. Since my Pi is offline but hosts the WLAN I expect the Smartphone to loose its connectivity to the internet.

How can I set up my Pi with Raspbian (no GUI) to act as an Access Point everyone can connect without loosing the internet connectivity provided e.g. by the cell network?

Comment: Did you try if the phone lose the internet connectivity or you are just guessing it? It's the behaviour I would expect but I never tried. Anyway, I think this is more related with how the smartphone works than with the Pi.

Comment: I tested it already with standard PCs. The Problem is that the Smartphone thinks the WLAN provides Internet but it doesnt. I don't know if it is even possible to disable this. Maybe some special Gateway settings must be set. Don't know even how to configure WLAN Hotspot without GUI, so I combined those two questions since I expect them to be highly dependant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to let the Smartphone create a tethering Hotspot and make the Pi connect to it. Then the Smartphone is able to connected to the Webserver on the Pi while still beeing able to talk to the internet. Additionally the Pi is able, too.

This did work for Android. Can someone confirm this for iOS?